# Create a function to run an update query and reduce the code in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, triggers

I am running various update queries in a trigger based on the inserted row in a table.

What I was thinking was to reduce the amount of code in the trigger to create functions for the update queries and then call the functions in the triggers.

Is this possible and how would the following update query look as a function for example?

```
UPDATE dbo.palletmove

SET NottsProcessDone = -1

WHERE palletmoveid = @palletMoveID and (Command = 6 or command = 7)
```

Thanks
Aaron

Comment: Which database technology are you working with?

Comment: Hi 
I am using SQL 2017.

Comment: 2014 is my experience. But with that, functions accessing tables seemed to be much slower. Keeping the actual query together allows sql server to generate better query plans. Same with views accessing other views. Better to copy the view internals together into one view.

Comment: Thanks Tamus.  That answers my question really.  I will keep it as is.

Comment: If that is your sample trigger code you have a MAJOR problem. You are using scalar variables which indicate you assume there will only ever be a single row in the inserted/delete tables. That is not how triggers work in sql server. They fire once per operation, not once per row. Trigger logic must be set based to work correctly.